# Static and dynamic web page

Tags: javascript, html

I am in a college course and having some issues. We had a quiz that ask where a static web page is generated? The options were: a. web browser b. web server c. application server d. database server

My answer was the web server as the web browser generates nothing merely displays the http return. The professor who I'm convinced is not overly well versed in this declared the web browser as what is generating the HTML.

My next question was when a dynamic page is generated with JavaScript where is the "script" ran? With the same possible answers as above. The options were: a. web browser b. web server c. application server d. database server

My answer was the application server. I know this may be incorrect. The professor once again proclaimed the web browser was the one running the script. Please help me understand!

Comment: A static web page can be stored on a server but is rendered by the browser. The dynamic web page using only script to generate the page is also generated and  rendered by the browser. The dynamic data used in the script could be ajaxed from the server

Comment: I won't confuse you with the special case of server side javascript, but javascript in general is ran in the browser. Traditional javascript is a client side language, meaning it is ran on the client's device in other words their web browser.

Comment: The key word in the first question is "generated". A static page really isn't generated anywhere in particular. Dreamweaver? Notepad? VSC? A file, like foo.html, is stored on a web server, requested by a client computer, and then rendered by their browser. The second question is too loose and open-ended, and could be answered in a variety of ways today. Maybe your professor is thinking 10 or 20 years ago?

Comment: @ mplungjan thank you for the quick response. So in your words would you say the web page is "generated" by the web browser? I agree it is rendered at the web browser but doesn't "generated" mean created or produced? I guess my issue is that the question is misleading.

Comment: your professor is correct here , the browser render the web page (i.e html and css) , the script is also run at browser side..here are some links to help you understand them better 1>  https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/performance/critical-rendering-path/render-tree-construction 2>  https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Performance/How_browsers_work

Comment: A problem of contention with me is the fact that they are using the term generated. Which implies `creation`. I guess web server would be the best option even though that is a stretch as I would argue a static page is generated on my computer then uploaded to the web server.

Answer (score 1):

I won't confuse you with the special case of server side javascript, but javascript in general is ran in the browser. Traditional javascript is a client side language, meaning it is ran on the client's device in other words their web browser. – imvain2

Thank you the way you describe it makes sense and why the professor has the answers as such.

The key word in the first question is "generated" a static page really isn't generated anywhere. A file, like foo.html, is stored on a web server, requested by a client computer, and rendered by their browser. – j08691

This is what I was thinking and my reasoning for answering the web server is what is producing the HTML Doc.